# How to install "Need For Speed - Most Wanted"

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, software-center

How to install the game "Need for Speed - Most Wanted" in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?
I tried the Ubuntu Software Center search engine but couldn't find it, nor did I found the .deb file through which I could easily install it using 'Gdebi package installer'. Can you help me?

Comment: i hope you know that this game must be buy, so you won't find it in the Ubuntu Software Center; you can try to have it with Steam : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus to install Steam on 16.04 -> probably you can install that game through this platform

Comment: @damadam Is there any other option? besides using steam?

Comment: go to the official website of the game studio of this game, but I'm pretty sure they didn't sold directly this game for Linux OS

Comment: @damadam what about the playonlinux? what is this application?

Comment: 1 question at same time; you will find better answer than mine by googled a little, but not really sure a paid game can be compatible with `playonlinux`, same for `wine`

Comment: Wine or playonlinux can run the Windows version https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35609 but these programs are not for helping you pirate a game, you need a valid windows version of the game to install (cracked versions WILL have issues) and a lisence key.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP comments indicte they want a paid product for free and that is piracy.

Comment: @MarkKirby I'd say that comment about how it should be possible to install a legally purchased copy of the Windows version of the game under Wine could be converted to an answer, instead of closing.

Comment: @damadam There isn’t any difference for Wine or PlayOnLinux whether the software is paid. You can use it to install MS Office which is also paid, isn’t it?

Comment: **@MarkKirby & CLOSE VOTERS:** This question and OP’s comments do _not_ explicitly involve software piracy. It is well possible that OP purchased the game for Windows before they switched to Ubuntu. Isn’t there any [presumption of innocence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presumption_of_innocence)?

Comment: There's an android version of the game which you can play on androidx86 in a vm on ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's assume that you have legally purchased copy of the game.

Then install PlayOnLinux with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Open PlayOnLinux [image: PlayOnLinux] with its launcher.

Afterwards click *Install*, type `most wanted`, select *Need For Speed Most Wanted*, click *Install*:

[image: Install NFS MW]

then follow instructions on screen.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, PlayOnLinux does not work, so I found the alternative to solve the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut